# Angular cannot use async pipe with my observables

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use async pipe in my template , but I have a problem getting data from my api.
I have used behavior subject to next the data and then keep it in an observable. When I call the observable in html I get this error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to
Iterables such as Arrays
```

**friendList.ts**

```
  public friendSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public friend$: Observable<any> = this.friendSubject.asObservable();


 getFriendList(userID: string) {
    userID = this.userID;
    try {
      return this.mainService.getFriendList(userID).subscribe((friendList) => {
        console.log(friendList)
        this.friendSubject.next(friendList);

        // friendList.data.forEach((friend => {
        // }))

        console.log(this.friendSubject)

      })
    }
    catch (err) {

    }
  }
```

**friendList.html**

```
  <ion-label class="friend-count" *ngIf="friend$ | async">{{(friend$ | async)?.length}}</ion-label> 
//this works..
   
            <div class="friend-list">
              <div *ngFor="let i = index; let friend of friend$ | async" class="friend">               
                  <div class="custom-img">
                    <ion-img class="friend-img" [src]="friend?.frendsView.photo"></ion-img>
                  </div>   
                  <ion-label></ion-label>             
    
              </div>

            </div>
```

[image]

I really want to understand why it doesn't work pls

Comment: Is it possible to provide a minimal reproducible example such as a StackBlitz? What does your comment "this works..." mean? Does it make any difference if you parenthesize `(friend$ | async)`?

Comment: try as follows *ngFor="let user of friend | async as friend; index as i"

Comment: The async pipe is working, the problem is that your `friend$` Observable is not of the type `Observable<any[]>` i.e Your Observable does not return an array rather it returns an Object.

Comment: yes , my observables return objects.. how can i transform it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you if you need to use a BehaviorSubject with an asynchronous pipeline.
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Your component:

```
friend$: Observable<[]> = [];

getFriendList(userId: string) {
  this.friend$ = this.mainService.getLastFriend(+userId).pipe(
    catchError(error => of(error))
  );
}
```

your mainService:

```
private friendSubject = new BehaviorSubject<[]>(null);
private users = [
    {
        userId: 1,
        name: 'Max',
        friendList: {
          {id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, 
          {id: 2, name: 'Alex'},
          {id: 3, name: 'Kate'}
        }
    }
];

getLastFriend(userId: number): Observable<[]> {
  const friendList = this.getFriendList(userId);
  this.friendSubject.next(friendList);

  return this.friendSubject.asObservable();
}  

private getFriendList(userId: number): [] {
  return of(users).pipe(
    filter( ({userId}) => userId === userId),
    map(user => user.friendList)
  );
}
```

Comment: There is a problem , in my code parameter 'userId' is used for getting all friends for the specified ID , not filtering friends , they are already filtered. I just need to show them and storing them in an observable.. Can you help me remake this short code pls?

Comment: sir i still cant use with my get request xd.. i have to map my object correcly and then i get errors with observables arrays.. and isnt there a way to simplify everything ? i just need the data , nothing in particular can't it just be a single function ?

Comment: Ok, what about this (array of objects):
`return this.mainService.getFriendList(userID).pipe( map(friendList => [friendList]),
tap(friendList => this.friendSubject.next(friendList))).subscribe()`